# set '\n\n' as the terminator when writing a formatted LogRecord

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to set `'\n\n'` as the terminator when writing a formatted LogRecord to a stream by changing  the `format` parameter of logging.basicConfig?

I know it is possible using the [`terminator` attribute of StreamHandler](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler) class to implement this,  I just wonder Is it possible to achieve this feature by changing  the `format` parameter? I am not familiar with the `format` string language

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes explains this very well, you could do something like:

```
"%(filename) %(funcname): %(message)\n\n"
```

Comment: ValueError: unsupported format character '?' (0xa) at index 10, tested with python3 code https://bpaste.net/show/dd254217b5da